# How to check null in lambda expression

Tags: asp.net

How to check for `null` in where condition in lambda expression?

```
listdropdownid.Id = listgroupid.Where(X => X.abc == desc).FirstOrDefault().abc_id.ToStr();
listdropdownid.Desc = desc;
```

If `abc == desc` fails, I need to assign `null` to `listdropdownid.Id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant way is to specify another default value using `DefaultIfEmpty(newValue)`:

```
listdropdownid.Id = listgroupid
    .Where(x => x.abc == desc)
    .Select(x => x.abc_id.ToString())
    .DefaultIfEmpty(null)  // would be more useful if you'd provide a more meaningful value like "<not found>"
    .First;
```

That works even with value types, in this case you could also use `FirstOrDefault` since the default value of `string` is already `null`. You just have to select it:

```
listdropdownid.Id = listgroupid
    .Where(x => x.abc == desc)
    .Select(x => x.abc_id.ToString())
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
listdropdownid = listgroupid.Where(X => X.abc == desc).FirstOrDefault();
if (listdropdownid != null)
{
   // Do something with listdropdownid.Id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
listdropdownid.Id = listgroupid.Where(X=>X!=null).Where(X => X.abc == desc).FirstOrDefault().abc_id.ToStr();
```